# Is it possible to close a script with a keypress?

Tags: terminal, keyboard, applescript, bash, automator

In AutoHotKey, using the keyword "ExitApp" can allow the user to stop a script with a keypress.  For example, `Esc::ExitApp` can stop a script by pressing "esc".

Now, with a combination of `do shell script` (using a bash function like `read`) and `on idle` and then calling `exit` somehow, I thought this was possible in AppleScript.  However, inside of an Automator function, you can't save an AppleScript as "stay open" - pasting the `on idle` thing underneath `on run` only loops through idle once without providing opportunities for listening for keypresses.  Any ideas?

Example:  Let's say I have this script in an automator workflow:

```
on run {input, parameters}
    set i to 0
     repeat while i < 100
       keystroke "a"
       set i to i + 1
       delay 5
     end repeat
end run
```

Comment: Why are you using **Automator** to run **AppleScript**, are there other _actions_ occurring before/after that you need it  to perform in conjunction with the **AppleScript**?

Comment: This may need to be closed. Can you edit in the post a script which would be eligible to be stopped? Interrupt handling and main loops are more of a swift and Objective-C idiom and scripts run to completion generally. Passing signals through named pipes sometimes works for pure shell scripts, but I don’t get why shell and AppleScript are chosen for this problem tbh.

Answer (score 0):

I’m not quite sure if my solution will help you or not.

I have a whole bunch of different **AppleScripts** attached to folders by use of **Folder Actions** and I also **run AppleScripts directly from the Script Menu in the menu bar**.

Occasionally one of my **AppleScripts** decides to misbehave and freezes or gets stuck and trying to quit the running **AppleScript** from the spinning gear in the menu bar does not work either.

My solution in these circumstances is to run this following **AppleScript** code.

```
tell application "System Events"
    set pidList to unix id of application processes whose name is "osascript"
end tell

set text item delimiters to space
do shell script ({"kill -9", pidList} as text)
set text item delimiters to ""
```

I saved the **AppleScript** code as a .scpt file and run it using **Voice Commands**, but you can just as easily use the code in a new A**utomator Quick Action** then assign it a keyboard shortcut in System Preferences.

---

***NOTE:** One of the drawbacks of this solution is that if you are running several scripts at the same time, this will force quit each one. As far as I know, there is no way of knowing which **osascript** belongs to which running **AppleScript**. (Not knowing which is which forces me to force quit each one.)*

Again, I don’t know if any of this will help you or not.  If nothing else maybe it will help spark some ideas for you.

Comment: Hm... when I log the pidList using script editor, there are no results.  It's quite odd - any ideas what could be wrong?

Comment: Furthermore, I tried doing ps -ax | grep "osascript" and for some odd reason the output looked the same whether or not an automator quick action was running.  https://imgur.com/a/z9bjohd

Comment: @Aaron  For the code to work, what is running needs to be a .scpt file. Not a script saved as an application or an Automator workflow or running a script through Script Editor. That was the reason I included the second sentence at the top of my post.

Comment: Ack!  I'll see if I can turn all my workflows into .scpt just to make everything a bit easier.
Well, keystrokes aren't working - I guess I'm stuck to closing them by hand ;-;